# type variables in constructors?

Tags: haskell

Can I have a function in a data constructor? Like:

```
data Something = (a->b) Something1 Something2
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah, of course you can. The only important thing is that you (always) need a name for your data constructor:

```
data <name> <para0> <param1> ... = <constructor> <arg0> <arg1> <arg2> ...
```

So for our example, it becomes

```
data Something a b = Constructor (a -> b) Something1 Something2
```

Comment: Here `Constructor` is a data constructor, not type constructor. The type constructor is `Something`. It is called type constructor because when you apply it to something, you have a type (`Something a b`), while if you apply a data constructor to something, you have some data (`Constructor f x y`).

Answer (score 5):

There are some rules to be followed in naming of a Constructor.

- Start with a uppercase letter.
- Can contain underscores, single quotes, letters and digits.
- Constructors can be operator names, so long as they start with a ':' .

But ofcourse you can have functions in a data definition like

```
data Something a b = Something (a->b) a b
```